# Value of type '1-dimensional array of Char' cannot be converted to x.ArrayOfChar

Tags: vb.net

I have a WebMethod in a legacy service. This service is currently a .NET 3.5 built application (Visual Studio 2008):

```
<WebMethod(EnableSession:=True)> _
Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As Char()) As MyAppUser
```

Then from within a VB.NET MVC .NET 4.5 client (Visual Studio 2012) I try to access Login. (I've changed a few variable names to not use our internal naming - so don't mind any typos - the same code works in Visual Studio 2008 see below).

```
Dim MyWebService as WebService.WebServiceClass = New WebService.WebServiceClass()
....
Dim encryptedPassword As String = EncryptString(password)
Dim rights As WebService.MyAppUser = MyWebService.Login(user, encryptedPassword.ToCharArray())
```

The problem is that the Visual Studio 2012 compiler has a problem with the encryptedPassword.ToCharArray() - giving a

```
Error    1    Value of type '1-dimensional array of Char' cannot be converted to 'WebService.WebServiceClass.ArrayOfChar'.
```

Within the Reference.vb from my client reference:

```
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThroughAttribute(),  _
 System.CodeDom.Compiler.GeneratedCodeAttribute("System.Runtime.Serialization", "4.0.0.0"),  _
 System.Runtime.Serialization.CollectionDataContractAttribute(Name:="ArrayOfChar", [Namespace]:="http://tempuri.org/", ItemName:="char"),  _
 System.SerializableAttribute()>  _
Public Class ArrayOfChar
    Inherits System.Collections.Generic.List(Of Char)
End Class
```

However, if I use the same code within a Windows .NET 3.5 web application (Visual Studio 2008) it compiles and works fine. I'd like to use ASP.NET MVC to make my life easier, but I can't seem to get over this little hurdle.

Comment: I do note that the reference.vb for the VB.NET v3.5 (VS2008) is substantially different - and is likely the reason that one works, the other doesn't.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error message indicated that `encryptedPassword.ToCharArray()` is returning an array when `ArrayOfChar` is the expected type, but I don't know why it worked in .NET 3.5.

Anyway, to get it to work, try to change this line:

```
Dim rights As WebService.MyAppUser = MyWebService.Login(user, encryptedPassword.ToCharArray())
```

to something like this:

```
Dim MyArrayOfChar As New ArrayOfChar
MyArrayOfChar.AddRange(encryptedPassword.ToCharArray())
Dim rights As WebService.MyAppUser = MyWebService.Login(user, MyArrayOfChar)
```

Comment: Thanks for this - I see what you did. I think the reason that it works in VS2008/v3.5 and not VS2012/v4.5 is how they complete the reference. The former is: Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password() As Char) As MyAppUser, whereas the latter is Public Function Login(ByVal username As String, ByVal password As SVEWebService.ArrayOfChar) As WebService.MyAppUser. Thanks.